# Maya Rigging - Shoulder joint attached to head?

Tags: animation, assets, maya, rigging

I'm fairly new to modeling and rigging in Maya; so my question is: in the image below how can I unbind the rigs head from the shoulder pivot? I've searched online for why this occurs and I can only guess that it's due to bad Joint placement?

[image: Broken Joint binds?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the bind method. Go into the ANIMATION menu set and select SKIN > BIND SKIN [options box] - and tell me which bind method you have selected.

I can then tell you how to weight your skin! :D

By the way, your joint placement is fine.

Comment: On my display for the SKIN drop down menu, i don't have the "Bind Skin option" however I know for a fact that i'm using Smooth bind to merge my skeleton with my model.

Comment: Okay try Googling "Maya Paint Skin Weights Tool" - Thats what you need.  There are other advanced ways of dealing with your issue, but the paint skin weights tools is a start. Also look up "Maya vertex weighting" - That should help too! Good luck! :D

Comment: Thanks JColling, I did some research and was able to learn about weigh painting for my character. All is good now, thank you for the answer anyhow <3

Comment: Good - I'm glad! If you need more help just ask. :D

Comment: If you go to WINDOWS >GENERAL EDITORS> COMPONENT EDITOR, you can click on SMOOTH SKINS tab. Next select a bone and it will show you all the vertices that are controlled by the selected bone - you can then modify the wighting of each vertex individually! A value of 1.0 is full influence and a value of 0.0 is no influence. Its a great way to get precision weighting in your models! Good luck to you! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add as an alternative -

You could simply use HUMANiK. Google that and youll get lots of helpful resources. It requires you deleting your old skeleton/bones, though. In the end, it is simpler to work with which is why I wanted to make you known to HumanIk. It may be right up your alley! Good luck, friend! :D